# How to solve too many parameters error when using makecert?

Tags: windows, ssl-certificate, makecert

I am following step 2 in [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx) tutorial. 
After entering this command,

```
makecert -r -pe -n "CN=PC-Name" -b 01/01/2000 -e 01/01/2036 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -ss my -sr localMachine -sky exchange -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12
```

I a getting ERROR: Too many parameters

How to solve this issue? Help please

Comment: note: makecert.exe is deprecated tool. You should avoid its use by using modern API (CertEnroll), certreq.exe tool (with updated INF syntax) or New-SelfSignedCertificate PowerShell cmdlet.

Answer (score 1):

The command looks like the following:

Makecert -r -pe -n CN="www.example.com" -b 05/10/2010 -e 12/22/2011 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -ss my -sr localmachine -sky exchange -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12

If you copy the sample command from the MSDN page above and run it via the command-line, you'll get error "Too many parameters". It turns out the dash used in the MSDN post above is actually character: \u2013 (DASH-EN) and not minus \u002D and it's the minus character that the tool is expecting.

So to make this work, simply replace the hyphen with the minus sign when keying in the command as defined above. In the above sample, I have replaced the incorrect character with the correct one so feel free to just copy and paste it.